# PhpStorm | File -> New Menu (ALT + Insert)

Tags: phpstorm

I'm not able to edit the file new menu when I hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd> in the project panel.

[image: File panel - create new file]

I can edit all right click menus in the settings (Appearance & Behavior -> Menus and Toolbars).

Is there a way to edit this menu?

Answer (score 1):

This menu can be edited in **Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars | Navigation Bar | New**

Comment: Sadly it's not :( I've edited this already, but the entries don't match up with what I have in this menu. (https://imgur.com/a/Z4Ifw)

Comment: doesn't indeed work... please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143090